The color package is not defining colors correctly
For some reason the color package is not defining even the base colors correctly for me --- let alone the dvips colors.  At least red, blue, yellow, and green are well defined.  But other colors seem to never become defined at all, even if they are Base Colors and are always supposed to be available.  When I run the code below I get three error messages indicating that the three colors used on my second sentence are not defined at all.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

This is \textcolor{red}{RED}, \textcolor{blue}{BLUE}, \textcolor{yellow}{YELLOW}, and \textcolor{green}{GREEN}.

But this is not \textcolor{brown}{BROUN}, nor \textcolor{gray}{GRAI}, nor \textcolor{orange}{OLENGE}, for example.

\end{document}

I am using MikTeX on Windows 10, and I get these same 3 errors regardless of whether I compile with LaTeX, with pdfLaTeX, or with XeTeX.
Yes, I know that if I use the xcolor package these errors go away, but I am curious as to what could possibly be going so wrong.

From the documentation (page 4):

The colours black, white, red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow should be predefined ....

Nothing about brown, orange or gray. If you are using the dvips driver is said to define 68 colours by default which can be accessed if you use this driver or load the relevant model. None of the 68 are, however, brown, orange or gray. They do, however, include Brown, Orange and Gray.
For example, this works with xelatex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips,usenames]{color}

\begin{document}

This is \textcolor{red}{RED}, \textcolor{blue}{BLUE}, \textcolor{yellow}{YELLOW}, and \textcolor{green}{GREEN}.

But this is not \textcolor{Brown}{BROUN}, nor \textcolor{Gray}{GRAI}, nor \textcolor{Orange}{OLENGE}, for example.

\end{document}

Or this for pdflatex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

This is \textcolor{red}{RED}, \textcolor{blue}{BLUE}, \textcolor{yellow}{YELLOW}, and \textcolor{green}{GREEN}.

But this is not \textcolor{Brown}{BROUN}, nor \textcolor{Gray}{GRAI}, nor \textcolor{Orange}{OLENGE}, for example.

\end{document}

Images currently unavailable due to Okular-on-X bug. The hoi polloi apologises for the inconvenience.

It appears that my error was in not including usenames in my declaration.  Both usenames and dvipsnames are needed.  Thank you for your answer.

@ltcomdata You also need to use the correct names: they're case-sensitive and all the 68 seem to be capped.

@cfr   Personally this is why I never load xcolor  with dvipsnames, best to always load it with no options and define your colors and I always use lowercase for color names.
